# Is there a JavaScript/HTML version of this Silverlight time navigation control?

Tags: javascript, ajax, silverlight, charts

Looking at this control that is made for Silverlight, and wondering where to find something similar for a pure HTML5 and JavaScript solution?

http://www.componentart.com/products/dv/timenavigator.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the linked site, it seems like that control does quite a variety of things, so while its unlikely that you'll get an exact replica of it in Javascript, you may well be able to find controls which have the specific features that you want.

With that in mind, I'd suggest taking a look at the following:

- [Timeline Widget](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/).
- [JSGantt](http://www.jsgantt.com/)
- [dygraphs JavaScript Visualization Library](http://dygraphs.com/)
- [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

(I also note that the one you linked to is 'Patent Pending', which means that they think they've done something unique and want to prevent anyone else doing something similar. Though looking at their charts on their homepage, I have to say I can't see anything particularly groundbreaking there)